# Interrupt Handler for Thread Event

Tags: python, multithreading

I am writing a class that creates threads that timeout if not used within a certain time. The class allows you to pump data to a specific thread (by keyword), and if it doesn't exist it creates the thread.

Anywho, the problem I have is main supervisor class doesn't know when threads have ended. I can't put blocking code like join or poll to see if it's alive. What I want is an event handler, that is called when a thread ends (or is just about to end) so that I can inform the supervisor that the thread is no longer active.

Is this something that can be done with signal or something similar?

As psuedocode, I'm looking for something like:

```
def myHandlerFunc():
    # inform supervisor the thread is dead

t1 = ThreadFunc()
t1.eventHandler(condition=thread_dies, handler=myHandlerFunc)
```

EDIT: Perhaps a better way would be to pass a ref to the parent down to the thread, and have the thread tell parent class directly. I'm sure someone will tell me off for data flow inversion.

EDIT: Here is some psuedocode:

```
class supervisor():
    def __init__:
        Setup thread dict with all threads as inactive

    def dispatch(target, message):
        if(target thread inactive):
            create new thread
        send message to thread

    def thread_timeout_handler():
        # Func is called asynchronously when a thread dies
        # Does some stuff over here


def ThreadFunc():
    while( !timeout ):
        wait for message:
            do stuff with message

    (Tell supervisor thread is closing?)
    return
```

The main point is that you send messages to the threads (referenced by keyword) through the supervisor. The supervisor makes sure the thread is alive (since they timeout after a while), creates a new one if it dies, and sends the data over.

Looking at this again, it's easy to avoid needing an event handler as I can just check if the thread is alive using threadObj.isAlive() instead of dynamically keeping a dict of thread statuses.

But out of curiosity, is it possible to get a handler to be called in the supervisor class by signals sent from the thread? The main App code would call the supervisor.dispatch() function once, then do other stuff. It would later be interrupted by the thread_timeout_handler function, as the thread had closed.

Comment: You don't provide much detail.  Are you using a message/event loop that can dispatch events?  What do you mean "inform supervisor the thread is dead"?  You say you don't want to block or poll, so what will your supervisor thread be doing in the meantime?

Comment: Added some more info.

Comment: Or perhaps it would be better to make another thread, that is passed a ref to the original thread and sits and waits for it to end, does some stuffs then dies. Seems a bit long winded though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You still don't mention if you are using a message/event loop framework, which would provide a way for you to dispatch a call to the "main" thread and call an event handler.

Assuming you're not, than you can't just interrupt or call into the main thread.

You don't need to, though, as you only need to know if a thread is alive when you decide if you need to create a new one.  You can do your checking at this time.  This way, you only need a way to communicate the "finished" state between threads.  There are a lot of ways to do this (I've never used .isAlive(), but you can pass information back in a Queue, Event, or even a shared variable).

Using [Event](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#event-objects) it would look something like this:

```
class supervisor():
    def __init__:
        Setup thread dict with all threads as inactive 

    def dispatch(target, message):
        if(thread.event.is_set()):
            create new thread
            thread.event = Event()
        send message to thread



def ThreadFunc(event):
    while( !timeout ):
        wait for message:
            do stuff with message

    event.set()
    return
```

Note that this way there is still a possible race condition.  The supervisor thread might check `is_set()` right before the worker thread calls `.set()` which will lie about the thread's ability to do work.  The same problem would exist with isAlive().

Is there a reason you don't just use a threadpool?

Comment: To be clear, I'm using Threading and passing data with a Queue. I'm not using ThreadPool simply because I've not heard of it - I'll take a look. Is there not a way to get a callback function from an event set?

Comment: Actually to give more context to the question, a thread is created every time a new user connects to the application. Users can come and go, so I had imaged a need to allow threads to timeout if a user never comes back. However, the thread just waits for a message that may never come. It shouldn't have any impact on performance, so maybe just create a thread when it's needed and leave it to rot? Perhaps the supervisor could keep track of stale threads, and close them.

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to create your own threadpool and dealing with management headaches of it.  There's one in the standard library (although not well documented) at multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool

Comment: Also, when you talk about "callback function", if you want that function to be called on the thread of the caller (the worker) or a new thread, that's easy.  But if instead you want it called on the main (supervisor) thread, that's impossible without some framework to make it possible (a message/event loop of some sort)